# How can I modify user privileges on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have `user1` and that user have 2 database, `database1` and `database2`..

I want to revoke/remove `database2` from `user1`, but `database2` still exist, `root` user still have `database2`.

I just want to remove `database2` from `user1`.

I try with this command `REVOKE ALL ON database1.* FROM 'user1';`

that command give me success result, but when I see with `show databases` on `user1`, `database1` still on the list..

but if run this command `REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES, GRANT OPTION FROM user1`,

that command will remove all databases that related to `user1`.

What is the right command to revoke/remove specific database from a user on MySQL/MariaDB?

Comment: Revoke I think must match the grant. Use `SHOW GRANTS FOR user1` and ensure your `REVOKE` matches. You might need a narrower grant for `user1 `to `database1` before removing some more global grant that encompassed `database2`.

Comment: here's the output `GRANT USAGE ON `database1`.* TO 'user1'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON database1.* FROM 'user1';
```

Comment: `GRANT USAGE ON `database1`.* TO 'user1'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION`

Answer (score 0):

in your case I would try the following:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

password

```
SHOW DATABASES;
```

We will see all database listed,suppose we want to drop the database : mike_database [IF EXISTS].

```
DROP SCHEMA  mike_database;
```

To check:

```
SHOW DATABASES;
```

Comment: is that save drop the schema instead using revoke?

Comment: I've tried it my self, works perfect on my debian, if you are not sure, try to make a testuser with a test database, and drop the database, the user will remain untouched.Greetings